# Need to have dynamic hidden field

Tags: php, jquery

I have script which allows the user to choose an image and write something about it...they choose the image from a JQuery slideviewer.

Now, choosing the image is easy..but how can I take the chosen image with the other form data? Each image is currently in a LI element

Code snippet:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.slideviewer.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE** I have now added this as suggested below but still not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#wl_add" ).submit( function ( event ) {

$( this ).find( "input[name='item_pic_url']" )
.val( $( "#mygalthree img" ).attr( 'src' ) );

} );
</script>

<div id="mygalthree" class="svw"><ul>
<?PHP

foreach($html->find('img') as $e){ // from simple_html_dom

$image = $e->src;

echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" width=300 alt="" /></li>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_pic_url" value="'.$image.'" />';

?>

</ul></div>
```

The hidden field in there now currently stores the last image added to the UL

Is there someoway to make a hidden field dynamic and then be changed depending on the image chosen - ideally i need the img src in the hidden field

Comment: Post your JavaScript & jQuery code used for choosing the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add another hidden field, `current_item_url` or whatever you want to call it.
2. Add a `submit` listener for the form.
3. In the `submit` listener, copy the `src` of the current image to the hidden field.

E.g. something like:

```
$( "#whatever-form" ).submit( function ( event ) {

  $( this ).find( "input[name='current_item_url']" )
    .val( $( "#mygalthree img" ).attr( 'src' ) );

} );
```

Alternatively, if the slideviewer fires an event or provides a callback you can hook into, you could update the value of the hidden field when the slide changes if you want.

Comment: changed the form name and input name to match but this simply not working...does the hidden field have value="" to start with or nothing at all e.g. no value attribute written... and does the above script go before or after the form? Or does it not matter

Comment: See here for an example and adapt as necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/vfu8e/ .  Inspect the `current_item_url` element, then submit the form and inspect it again.  As in the example, I'd put `value=""` in the hidden `input` initially, but whether you do that or omit the attribute its value will default to being empty string.  The script doesn't need to come before the form if you put it inside `$( document ).ready()`, otherwise it would need to come after the form so that the element is in the DOM when you try to attach the `submit` listener.

Answer (score 0):

When the click event happens, update the hidden field like this:

```
$( 'item_pic_url' ).value( 'selected_image_identifier' );
```